# looping to generate unique id javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get unique id in my javascript so, i make a looping and put it after the name of id.
Here is my HTML code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var a;
      for (a = 1; a < 300; a++)
        // if checked   add value
        $("#abc" + a).val($('#xyz' + a).attr('value'));
    } else {
      // if unchecked remove value
      $("#abc" + a).val("");
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" />
<input type="text" id="xyz1" name="xyz1" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="abc1" name="abc1" />

<input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" />
<input type="text" id="xyz2" name="xyz2" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="abc2" name="abc2" />
```

And here is my javascript code:

I add "a" after id name in order to generate the same id with text. But it still didn't working well..
Anyone can help me? I really Appreciates for any helping :-)

Comment: Are there 300 `input` elements at `html` ? What is purpose of `for` loop ?

Comment: No. It's just max looping value. The purpose from for loop is to generate unique id. So, I add "a" after #abc.

Comment: You should really add {} around the for loop and you didn't need the ; after the if statement.

Comment: You're generating unique IDs `#abc1` through `#abc299` in the for loop and setting the value of the related element to the value of the corresponding unique ID `#xyz1` to `#xyz299` elements. That much is set in your existing code. What's not clear is the problem - what do you mean by "it still doesn't work well"? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: Other than the for loop, The only thing missing is the jquery .... but I think that is all of it...

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, sir :-)

http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/dGKvBL/

You need to add this to the head:

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I was going to add this as well, you beat me to it! Here's a jsFiddle version for kicks ha: https://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/mwvg36b6/

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    for(var a = 1; a < 300; a++){
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
        // if checked   add value
        $("#abc"+a).val($('#xyz'+a).attr('value'));
      }else{
        // if unchecked remove value
        $("#abc"+a).val("");
      }    
    }
  });
});
```

Update :

Considering the updated code in the question, if you have a common pattern like a checkbox and 2 fields repeating like given in the question, I suggest you to use a class instead of generating unique ID each time.

```
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" />
<input class="xyzs" type="text" id="xyz1" name="xyz1" value="3"/>
<input class="abcs" type="text" id="abc1" name="abc1" />

<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" />
<input class="xyzs" type="text" id="xyz2" name="xyz2" value="5"/>
<input class="abcs" type="text" id="abc2" name="abc2" />
```

Now the jquery would be something like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click',function(){
  $(".chk").each(function(i,ch){
    var abc = $(".abcs");
    var xyz = $(".xyzs");
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(abc[i]).val($(xyz[i]).val());
    }else{
      $(abc[i]).val(" ");
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for helping. But the result is same with what i've done. any other suggest? @dvenkatsagar

Comment: I actually didnt understand what you are trying to do? if you click the checkbox, you want to fill all the textboxes that have certain id with some value??

Comment: yes. So, when I click checkbox the value from id "xyz" appeared in id "abc". @dvenkatsagar

Comment: The solution I have given is doing that, I guess.... What should expected output look like??

Comment: Ops sorry. I've updated my code it have two checkbox.. The result expected is show xyz value into abc text when checkbox checked. @dvenkatsagar

Comment: I've already try it but the value didn't show up in text. @dvenkatsagar

Comment: Ya sorry, found the mistake, now tested it. It should work as expected

Comment: Awesome. It works. You're great @dvenkatsagar. Thanks :-)

Comment: I want to ask something. Is it okay when class have same name? @dvenkatsagar

Comment: Ya classes can be same, id must be unique..... But when you select via class, you would need to loop it as it would return an array of elements. But if its ID, you can select the individual element.

Comment: Yaa. Thanks @dvenkatsagar. It really helps. I appreciates you.

Comment: How to mark it as useful? I'm new in stackoverflow.

Comment: On the left side of the solution, you can accept this answer("the tick mark") if it solved your problem or upvote it("the up arrow") if you found it useful or do both.

Comment: I have this following array code: <input type="text" id="id$i" name="name$i" /> And I want to insert them into database with POST method. I put $i after id to create unique id. I make $i from for loop with $i = 1; $i++. So, the result will be like this: <input type="text" id="id1" name="name1" /> <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" /> etc. So, my question is what can I do if I want to insert this data with POST method.? Pleasee help @dvenkatsagar

Comment: This will be off-topic, and you might want to post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, following code is causing issue

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  var a;
  for (a = 1; a < 300; a++)
    // if checked   add value
    $("#abc" + a).val($('#xyz' + a).attr('value'));
} else {
  // if unchecked remove value
  $("#abc" + a).val("");
```

If you notice, if `$(this).is(":checked")` is unchecked, `a` is undefined and hence it is not setting value. Also, condition to set should be inside loop and not outside it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    for (a = 1; a < 300; a++) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var a;
        // if checked   add value
        $("#abc" + a).val($('#xyz' + a).attr('value'));
      } else {
        // if unchecked remove value
        $("#abc" + a).val("");
      };
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" />
<input type="text" id="xyz1" name="xyz1" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="abc1" name="abc1" />

<input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" />
<input type="text" id="xyz2" name="xyz2" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="abc2" name="abc2" />
```

You can event try something like this:

instead of a loop for `300` iterations, you can search using `id` and assign value. You can fetch elements with similar `id` or `name` using `$([attribute^=value])`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var val = $(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).parent().find("[id^=xyz]").val() : "";
    $(this).parent().find("[id^=abc]").val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" />
  <input type="text" id="xyz1" name="xyz1" value="3" />
  <input type="text" id="abc1" name="abc1" />
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" />
  <input type="text" id="xyz2" name="xyz2" value="5" />
  <input type="text" id="abc2" name="abc2" />
</div>
```

Comment: It should be when "check1" checked, text "abc1" display value 3 and when "check2" checked text abc2 display value 5.

Comment: If thats the case, we should be able to navigate to nodes using `this` and not use loop

Comment: Yeah I see. Thanks for helping me @Rajesh.

Comment: @RezaM I have updated my answer to navigate using `this`. Also I have taken liberty to updated HTML. Do check that as well.

Comment: Wow amazing. It's work well as expected :-). Thanks @Rajesh

Comment: I have an issue with my code. I have this following array code: <input type="text" id="id$i" name="name$i" /> And I want to insert them into database with POST method. I put $i after id to create unique id. I make $i from for loop with $i = 1; $i++. So, the result will be like this: <input type="text" id="id1" name="name1" /> <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" /> etc. So, my question is what can I do if I want to insert this data with POST method.? Pleasee help @Rajesh

Comment: So per my understanding, you have an array and you generate html from it. Now you want to save entire HTML in database. Well to do that, you can create an HTML string instead of appending elements in loop and assign this html using `.html()`. Also, I dont think its best to save entire HTML in db. Rather save data and generate your html using javascript